# Overwrite Highcharts X Axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to show multiple lines on a chart plotting numbers and dates. I want to X Axis to always show all the months, starting at January through to December, even if there is only data for, say, february and march. I have created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ejjtc73h/1/). How can I do this? You can see in the fiddle that only the months I have data for show.

I would also like the X axis to show 'Jan', 'Feb' etc, and no numbers. Is this possible?

My code so far is:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Chart reflow is set to true'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'When resizing the window or the frame, the chart should resize'
    },


    xAxis: {
        type: "datetime"
    },

    series: [{
        data:[[1456444800000,173682],[1456531200000,21136],[1457049600000,21136],[1457395200000,199158],[1457913600000,413265],[1458777600000,21136],[1459209600000,199158],[1459987200000,413265],[1460505600000,21136],[1461024000000,199158],[1461715200000,413265],[1462406400000,199158]]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a `min` and `max` value for your x axis:

```
xAxis: {
  type: "datetime",
  tickInterval:86400000 * 30,
  min: Date.UTC(2016,0,1),
  max: Date.UTC(2016,11,31)
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ejjtc73h/2/